# Sitefinity Slow Initial Page Load on Debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, telerik, sitefinity

`Telerik.Sitefinity` initial page load is taking about 25 seconds to load in debugging mode. Has anybody overcome this issue? This is the image stays showing until the site loads.

[image]

Any help appreciate.

Comment: That's normal if you have just built the project (or changed some of the Feather views).

Comment: It's normal for Sitefinity. In very big projects, cold start time might take a lot of time, more than a minute

Comment: Some tips here https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Sitefinity-startup-performance

Answer (score 2):

The best suggestion I have, is to upgrade your site to version 10.1 - as they have cut the startup time in half:

https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/vladimir-vasilev-blog/2017/07/13/sitefinity-cuts-web-site-startup-time-in-half

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.